# Is there any tool or method to debug an error about `open fileXXX: Operation not permitted?`

Tags: linux, systemd, capabilities

I have a running program trying to open and write to a file under systemd folder:

`/etc/systemd/system/mysqld_3310.service.d/u_iops_value`

but got this error:

> write /etc/systemd/system/mysqld_3310.service.d/u_iops_value error: open /etc/systemd/system/mysqld_3310.service.d/u_iops_value: operation not permitted

The problem is after checking file permissions and the program's running user, it's all correct, and I have no clue what to do next due to inexperience.

For a situation like this, what should I do next?

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled? You can check by running `getenforce`.

Comment: Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Comment: @Haxiel SELinux is disabled

Comment: Perhaps the issue is not that you cannot read the file, but you cannot 'execute' (ie look at the contents of) one of the parent directories? Try running `ls -l /etc/systemd/system/` and confirming that you have access to the `.../mysqld_3310.service.d` directory.